# Probability Distribution of each unique numbers in an array (length unknown) after excluding zeros

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, probability-density

Part of my datafile looks as

```
ifile.txt
1
1
3
0
6
3
0
3
3
5
```

I would like to find probability of each numbers excluding zeros. e.g. P(1)=2/8; P(3)=4/8 and so on

Desire output

```
ofile.txt
1  0.250
3  0.500
5  0.125
6  0.125
```

Where 1st column shows the unique numbers except 0 and 2nd column shows the probability. I was trying as following, but looks very lengthy idea. I am facing problem in for loop, as there are so many unique numbers

```
n=$(awk '$1 > 0 {print $0}' ifile.txt | wc -l)
for i in 1 3 5 6 .....
do
n1=$(awk '$1 == $i {print $0}' ifile.txt | wc -l)
p=$(echo $n1/$n | bc -l)
printf "%d %.3f\n" "$i $p" >> ofile.txt
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an associative array in `awk` to get the count of each unique number in one pass.

```
awk '$0 != "0" { count[$0]++; total++ } 
     END { for(i in count) printf("%d %.3f\n", i, count[i]/total) }' ifile.txt | sort -n > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a `sort | uniq -c` to get the distinct number counts in ~n log n instead of n^2 time, and then run that through division by your total non-zero count from `wc -l`?

Comment: Thank you @Novelocrat for your suggestion. But I couldn't able to solve it until snd's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using [Novelocrat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31467599/3430492)'s `sort|uniq -c` suggestion:

```
sed '/^0/ d' ifile.txt|sort|uniq -c >i
awk 'FNR==NR{n+=$1;next;}{print $2,$1/n}' i i
```

**short explanation**

remove numbers starting with 0's `sed '/^0/ d' ifile.txt`

`sort|uniq -c >i` gives you `i`:

```
   2 1
   4 3
   1 5
   1 6
```

In awk, `FNR==NR{n+=$1;next;}` totals col 1 of `i` in `n` (`next` skips the next command), and then `print $2,$1/n` prints col 2 of `i` and the quotient of col 1 over `n`.

Comment: `/0/!p` will also remove `10`, `20`, etc.